# BNK-3R terminal secretions drop anything good?

Tags: borderlands-2

> In addition to the loot strewn across the Bunker, BNK-3R will continue to "drip" loot from its main cannon several times.

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/BNK-3R#Notes

After destroying the BNK-3R, it spouts some loot for some time afterwards. It seems like the loot is never legendary. It is time-consuming to wait for it to finish. Is it ever at least purple-rarity? More particularly, is it ever legendary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BNK-3R can drop a legendary SMG http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bitch_(Borderlands_2), and a legendary absorb shield http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sham

There are videos where people have gotten a legendary item from the 'cannon drip'
[video here](https://youtu.be/Qo6SBbqy8v8?t=168)

Comment: I know, but what about the terminal secretions?

Comment: @NiteCyper I have found a video of a legendary weapon 'dripping' https://youtu.be/Qo6SBbqy8v8?t=168